# Change the database's table in hive or hcatalog

Tags: hive, hcatalog

Is there a way to change the database's table in hive or Hcatalog?

For instance, I have the table `foo` in the database `default`, and I want to put this table in the database `bar`. I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO bar.foo
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way in HiveQL to do this. A **[ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2496)** was raised long back though. But the issue is still open.

An alternate could be to use the **EXPORT/IMPORT** feature provided by Hive. With this feature we can export the data of a table to a HDFS file along with the metadata using the **EXPORT** command. The data is stored in **JSON** format. Data once exported this way could be imported back to another database (even another hive instance) using the **IMPORT** command.

More on this can be found on the **[IMPORT/EXPORT MANUAL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport)**.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your response. I found an other mean to change the database

`USE db1; CREATE TABLE db2.foo like foo`